# Can't get int from database and use it PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to do a money system in PHP to a game where if you click a button money value is sent from the database to PHP which adds the money var to 10 and sends the new value back to the database but I can't get the value from the database. please, can someone help me :)

```
if (isset($_POST['sds'])) {
$money = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT money FROM testing WHERE name='currentMoney'");

$money += 10;

$sql = "UPDATE testing SET money = $money WHERE name='currentMoney'";
mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);

echo $money;

}
```

I do not have a money value outside of this if statement

Comment: You haven't fetched a row or accessed the row variable or anything.  Do some research:

Comment: You just run the query not fetching any row, that's why, you are not getting id

Comment: I'd recommend using prepared statements, they are a lot more secure

Comment: `SET money = $money` pretty sure there shouldn't be a `$` here. If so, then that's a huge security risk you're taking.

Comment: Based off that code, just `UPDATE testing SET money = (money + 10) WHERE name='currentMoney'` would work all by itself... don't even need to prepare it ;)

Comment: @Simon It's a potential security hole. If you should happen to rely on user input, a potential hacker could arbitrarily inject into it, and modifying your `SET money = $money` to something else. At best, you could add `(int)` to the variable's assignment which would help. Same potential security hole with `WHERE name='currentMoney'`, should that later on come from user inputted data.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($_POST['sds'])) {
   $query= mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT money FROM testing WHERE name='currentMoney'");
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); // you need to fetch the row, to get the id
   $id = $row['your_db_col_name'];
   $money = $row['your_db_col_name'];
   $money += 10;
}
```

You need to fetch the row using [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: shouln't it be `mysqli_fetch_array`?